# How to remove SKSpriteNodes after specific amount of time

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to add SKSpriteNodes and place them randomly in the scene with specific time interval. Then I want these nodes to be removed after a specific time.

The problem is that the removal does not work.

I try to use removeFromParent() in a SKAction.sequence but the code is not executed.

How can I remove SKSpriteNodes after specific amount of time?

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(placeFruit),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)
            ])))
}

func placeFruit() {

    let fruit = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "apple")
    fruit.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width * random(min: 0, max: 1), y: frame.size.height * random(min: 0, max: 1))

    addChild(fruit)

    runAction(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0),
            SKAction.removeFromParent()
            ]))
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
}

func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
}

func random(#min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return random() * (max - min) + min
}

}
```

Comment: You are applying the action to `self` (i.e., the scene) not the sprite. If you change the `runAction` in the `placeFruit` method to `fruit.runAction.sequence...` the sprite will be removed from the scene.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are running your sequence action on `self` instead of your `fruit` node.

Simply change your function like so :

```
func placeFruit() {

    let fruit = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "apple")
    fruit.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width * random(min: 0, max: 1), y: frame.size.height * random(min: 0, max: 1))

    addChild(fruit)

    fruit.runAction(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0),
            SKAction.removeFromParent()
        ])
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func makeSpriteNode () {
  var spriteNodelabel        = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "imagename")
  spriteNodelabel.position   = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: frame.size.height*0.90)
  spriteNodelabel.size       = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width*0.70, frame.size.height*0.06)
  spriteNodelabel.alpha      = 0.2
  //Position of SpriteNode
  spriteNodelabel.zPosition  = 21.0
  self.addChild(spriteNodelabel)
  //Action to remove SpriteNode
  spriteNodelabel.runAction(
    SKAction.sequence([
        //Here we define Time duration in With SpriteNode remove!
        SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0),
        SKAction.removeFromParent()
        ])
  )
}
```

Use this function to create SKSpriteNode! It will remove after 1 second delay!